appsettings.json for UWP
I have been following these instructions to configure the database connection string in an UWP app:
https://mzikmund.dev/blog/using-appsettings-json-in-uwp
The app is working as expected. However, I can't find the location where the information is stored once the app has been deployed which makes it impossible to change the connection string after deployment. I have checked the c:users[user]\AppData\Local\Packages[Package ID] folder but while I have find other settings, I have not found the information contained in the appsettings.json file.

I found the appsettings.json file in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps[Package ID], the same folder in which the executable is also saved.
